# Independence of First-Order Peano Axioms

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

In class was given these 7 (first-order) axioms of Peano arithmetic (the + denotes successor):

> NT1 $\quad(\forall x) \neg\left(x^{+}=\overline{0}\right)$
> NT2 $\quad(\forall x)(\forall y)\left(x^{+}=y^{+} \Rightarrow x=y\right)$
> NT3 Schema: for every expression $P$ and variable symbol $x$
> $$
> P(\overline{0}) \Rightarrow\left((\forall x) P(x) \Rightarrow P\left(x^{+}\right)\right) \Rightarrow(\forall x) P(x)
> $$
> NT4 $\quad(\forall x)(x+\overline{0}=x)$
> NT5 $\quad(\forall x)(\forall y)\left(x+y^{+}=(x+y)^{+}\right)$
> NT6 $\quad(\forall x)(x \cdot \overline{0}=0)$
> NT7 $\quad(\forall x)(\forall y)\left(x \cdot\left(y^{+}\right)=(x \cdot y)+x\right)$

The task is to prove that these axioms are independent. I have figured out that to do this, I must take each axiom and find a model in which it does not hold - but all of the others do. For example, I (think) I have proved that NT1 does not hold for integers modulo (say) 5 and that NT7 does not hold true for the even natural numbers. I cannot think of how to prove NT4,NT5,NT6 because I have never come across a model in which this is not true.

For NT4, I thought of artificially creating a model in which $0+1=0$; but then NT5 would not hold because $
(0+1)^{+}=0^{+}=1 ; \quad 0+1^{+}=0+2=2
$.
I also thought of trying a model ${0,1,2,...,n}$ in which $0+n = n+1$ for all $n$, but of course this would violate NT2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: a maybe dumb question : in what theory will you write your proof that the PA are independent ? how do you know that the choice of that theory doesn't change the result (if they are independent or not) ? and if that theory was inconsistent, wouldn't you be able to prove anything, for example that the PA are not independent ?

Comment: @user1952009: It's not a dumb question, but usually we assume the meta-system is something sufficiently strong such as $ZF$.

Comment: There seems to be nothing in the images that could not be typed on this site - that would make the question self contained and easier to answer. It is not good practice on this site to use images when text would suffice. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for information on how to type mathematics.

Comment: @reuns I believe that modulo the assumption that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent, the independence of these axioms can be proven in a very weak base system, such as $\mathsf{I}\Sigma_1$, which is significantly weaker than $\mathsf{PA}$ itself.